# problem with drag and drop | draggable event gets trigged on children

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have a board which has 10 rows and 10 columns and 3 ships which have 1 row and 3 columns.
what I want is when I hover one of my ship over board's column all the columns I am currently hovering over my ship should have a specific background color.
I have set "dragover" event to all the columns and I have set "draggable true event to all the ships".
but the problem is when I drag my ship onto the board only 1 column gets background color, and another problem is "dragover" event is only get triggered when the specific column of the ship is gets hovered on it.
suppose I click on the 3rd column of my ship and start dragging then the board's column's background colour will only change when that third column is hovered onto the column.
Ik it sounds confusing, its becuse of my bad english :/

script.js

```
import dragandrop from "./dragAndDrop.js";

const board = document.querySelector(".board");
const shipsContainer = document.querySelector(".ships");

// creating 10 row and 10 columns board
function renderBoard() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement("div");
    row.classList.add(`row-${i}`, "row");
    board.appendChild(row);

    for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
      const column = document.createElement("div");
      column.classList.add(`row-${i}-column-${j}`, "column");
      row.appendChild(column);
    }
  }
}

// creating 3 ships of 3x3
function renderShips() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    const ship = document.createElement("div");
    ship.classList.add(`ship-${i}`, "ship");
    ship.setAttribute("draggable", "true");

    shipsContainer.appendChild(ship);
    for (let j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
      const shipColumn = document.createElement("div");
      shipColumn.classList.add(`ship-column-${j}`, "ship-column");
      ship.appendChild(shipColumn);
    }
  }
}

renderBoard();
renderShips();
dragandrop();
```

dragAndDrop.js

```
export default function dragandrop() {
  const columns = document.querySelectorAll(".column");
  const ships = document.querySelectorAll(".ship");

  ships.forEach((ship) => {
    ship.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log("ship started dragging");
    });
  });

  columns.forEach((column) => {
    column.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
      column.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="board"></div>

      <div class="ships-container">
        <div class="ships"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.board {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(400px / 10);
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.column {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% / 10);
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.column:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}

.ships-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.ships {
  width: 100%;
  height: 76.5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.ship {
  width: min-content;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ship-column {
  width: 39px;
  height: 39px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.ship-column:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to create a battleship game. The reason behind *"when I drag my ship onto the board only 1 column gets background color"* is the listeners fllow your mouse not the element itself. So in order to mimic the width of the ship, you have to adjust the columns nearby the dragover element. I hope this answers your question.

```js
function dragandrop() {
  const columns = document.querySelectorAll(".column");
  const ships = document.querySelectorAll(".ship");
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll(".row");

  let shipColumnIndex;
  let shipIndex;


  ships.forEach((ship,sIndex) => {
    ship.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      shipIndex = sIndex;
      console.log("ship started dragging");
    });
    ship.addEventListener("dragend", (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      const draggedColumns = document.querySelectorAll(".draggingRed");
      const errorColumns = document.querySelectorAll(".errorRed");
      draggedColumns.forEach((column) => {
        column.classList.add("dragendRed")
      })
      errorColumns.forEach((column) => {
        column.classList.remove("errorRed")
      })
    });
    ship.querySelectorAll(".ship-column").forEach((shipColumn,index) => {
      shipColumn.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        shipColumnIndex = index;
      })
    })
  });

  columns.forEach((column) => {
    column.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
      const rowId = column.parentElement.getAttribute("rowId")
      const columnId = column.getAttribute("columnId")
      const shipLength = ships[shipIndex].querySelectorAll(".ship-column").length;
      backgroundPainter(rowId,columnId,shipLength);
    });
  })
  function backgroundPainter(rowId,columnId,shipLength){
    //fillCheck checks if the ship can fit in the grid
    const fillCheck = columnId-shipColumnIndex+shipLength-1 <rows.length && columnId-shipColumnIndex  > -1;
    //clear the background while moving
    columns.forEach((column) => {
      column.classList.remove("draggingRed")
      column.classList.remove("errorRed")
    });
    for(let i = 0;i < shipLength;i++){
      let gridBox = rows[rowId].children[columnId-shipColumnIndex+i]
      //check if there is a grid element
      if(gridBox){
        if(fillCheck){
          //if the ship fits in the grid
          gridBox.classList.add("draggingRed");
        }
        else{
          //if the ship does not fit in the grid
          gridBox.classList.add("errorRed");

        }
      }
    } 
  }
};


const board = document.querySelector(".board");
const shipsContainer = document.querySelector(".ships");

// creating 10 row and 10 columns board
function renderBoard() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement("div");
    row.classList.add(`row-${i}`, "row");
    row.setAttribute("rowId", i-1);

    board.appendChild(row);

    for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
      const column = document.createElement("div");
      column.classList.add(`row-${i}-column-${j}`, "column");
      column.setAttribute("columnId", j-1);
      row.appendChild(column);
    }
  }
}

// creating 3 ships of 3x3
function renderShips() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    const ship = document.createElement("div");
    ship.classList.add(`ship-${i}`, "ship");
    ship.setAttribute("draggable", "true");

    shipsContainer.appendChild(ship);
    for (let j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
      const shipColumn = document.createElement("div");
      shipColumn.classList.add(`ship-column-${j}`, "ship-column");
      ship.appendChild(shipColumn);
    }
  }
}

renderBoard();
renderShips();
dragandrop();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .board {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .row {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(400px / 10);
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .row:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  
  .column {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% / 10);
    border-right: 1px solid black;
  }
  
  .column:last-of-type {
    border-right: none;
  }
  
  .ships-container {
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .ships {
    width: 100%;
    height: 76.5%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1rem;
  }
  
  .ship {
    width: min-content;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .ship-column {
    width: 39px;
    height: 39px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
  }
  .ship-column:last-of-type {
    border-right: none;
  }
  .dragendRed{
    background-color: red;
  }
  .draggingRed{
    background-color: red;
  }
  .errorRed{
    background-color: yellow;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="board"></div>

      <div class="ships-container">
        <div class="ships"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also added some extra features in order to not allow users to add ships on the board if the whole ship does not fit in the board.